# Converting 8.24 fixed point , 0.000000000000000 to 1.000000000000000 range to uint32_t in C

Tags: c, fixed, point

I'd like to convert 8.24 fixed point numbers from within range of\

```
0.000000000000000 -> 1.000000000000000 to uint32_t
```

Do I multiply decimal places or add or bitshift ?

I am receiving the 8.24 format fixed point numbers as 4 bytes

```
    uint8_t meterDataRX[4];

    // read 4 bytes from DSP channel
       HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&I2cHandle,bbboxDsp_address,meterDataRX,4,1); 

    uint32_t a;

    a = (meterDataRX[0] << 24) | (meterDataRX[1] << 16) | (meterDataRX[2] << 8) | meterDataRX[3];
```

But not sure this is correct to start with!

The goal is to make values between `uint8_t` of `0x00` to `0xFF` but should I make `uint32_t` values from 4 bytes 1st? the cast

```
    uint8_t b;
    b = (uint8_t)a;
```

Comment: For some specified value of `a`, what is the expected result of `(uint8_t)a`? And if you haven't done it yet, then please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And go back to your books, tutorials or class notes and review what they say about conversions and casting.

Comment: This isn't possible because there is no room. You cannot store 8 bytes in 4 bytes. Specifically: `1.000000000000000` equals 10^15. The maximum value of a `uint32_t` is 2^32 = 4.29*10^9. But it is perfectly unclear where the value `1.000000000000000` came from, did you just make it up out of the blue? I will not be returned by that function. What does the actual code look like?

Comment: What do you mean by "converting"? Does the result of the conversion have to preserve some numeric properties of the original number? Which ones? What should be the result of the conversion of e.g. the number 447.175?

Comment: @lundin 8.24 has 32 bits not 8 bytes

Comment: @P__J__ Yes, so the question doesn't make any sense and needs to be clarified.

Comment: To be clear, when you say `1.000000000000000` do you mean 1? In a 8.24 fixed point notation, sholudn't its representation be 00000001.000000000000000000000000b?

Comment: OK, thanks for all the replies. I have this all completely wrong !!! It turns out I was viewing a 32bit unsigned int in 8.24 format in the DSP software.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the 4 byte, 8.24 fixed byte number as a 32-bit number. For a real number in the range 0 to 1 inclusive, the '8.24' fixed point number will be represented as a 32-bit number in the range 0 to 0x01000000 (integer part is 1, fractional part is 0). You wish to scale this to a number the range 0 to 0xFF.

1. Optional step: clamp out-of-range input number to a maximum value of 0x01000000:

   `if (a > 0x01000000) a = 0x01000000;`
2. Multiply by 0xFF to give a number in the range 0x00000000 to 0xFF000000:

   `a *= 0xFF;`
3. Optional step: for rounding rather than truncating, add the '8.24' fixed point representation of the real value 0.5, which is 0x00800000:

   `a += 0x00800000;`
4. Shift right by 24 bits to strip the fractional part:

   `a >>= 24;`

You will be left with a number in the range 0 to 0xFF.

Note that if you skip step 1 (clamping out-of-range numbers), inputs greater than 0x01008080 (representing the real value 1.00196075439453125) will result in arithmetic overflow. If you skip both steps 1 (clamping) and 3 (rounding), inputs greater than 0x01010101 (representing the real value 1.003921568393707275390625) will result in arithmetic overflow.

Answer (score 0):

if the value is between 0 and 1 you need to scale  it.

but if you want to just store it in the uint32  variable you need to change the order as now (in your code) your data is big endian but stm32  uCs  use little endian.

```
    a = ((uint32_t )meterDataRX[0] ) | ((uint32_t )meterDataRX[1] << 8) | ((uint32_t )meterDataRX[2] << 16) | ((uint32_t )meterDataRX[3] <<24);
```

you van also use union pinning for it

Comment: yes the value is 0 to 1. the bytes are being read from other hardware but arrive on stm32f7 , how do I change to little endian? do i just do the same in reverse?

Comment: I got this completely wrong !!! I was just viewing normal uint32_t numbers in 8.24 format in the DSP software.

Answer (score 0):

For 8.24 fixed point, each `uint32_t` (or equivelent) would hold a number in the range from 00000000.000000000000000000000000b to 11111111.111111111111111111111111b.

For a floating point number in the range 0.000000000000000 to 1.000000000000000, you'd have to multiply it by `(1 << 24)` before converting it to an unsigned integer; so that you end up with 8.24 fixed point.

For a `uint8_t` where 0x00 represent 0.0 and 0xFF represents 0.996; you'd have to multiply it by `(1 << (24-8))` (or shift it left 16 places) to convert it to 8.24 fixed point.

For a `uint8_t` where 0x00 represent 0.0 and 0xFF represents 1.0; you'd have to multiply it by `(1 << 24)` (or shift it left 24 places) and then divide by 0xFF to convert it to 8.24 fixed point.

To convert 8.24 fixed point back to either of the cases above, you'd do the reverse (e.g. multiply by 0xFF then shift right by 24 places to get back to `uint8_t` where 0xFF represents 1.0).

Comment: now i'm not sure its fixed point, but the numbers are 0.0 to 1